# Add a static method to my Laravel models or make the trait Dynamic

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am using this below trait by default add the authenticated user_id to each query but sometimes I want to use another user_id so if there is any way to add that user_id as a parameter or another function please help me

```
static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) {
$id = null;
$role = auth()->user()->roles;
                
if (auth()->check()) {
    if ($role[0]->id == 1) {
        $id = auth()->id();
    } else {
        $id = auth()->user()->user_id;
    }
}
              
return $builder->where((new self())->getTable() .'.user_id', $id)
               ->orWhere((new self())->getTable() .'.user_id', 0);
```

});

i need to work with the models because of the pivot

Comment: Your approach seems off, normally you would filter this out through a normal scope. Can you explain why you need this and maybe this would help people / me understand the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: my application is multi users i need this so not everytime i use the Auth::id() to display the logged-in user data and there are sub users who they have some of the user's privilege's  the user cerate's these sub users but also there are sub users which don't belong to any user but the user can give them some tasks to do so in the users that aren't belong to anyone i can't make them do some of the tasks provided by the user i need to do that using Elequent because of the Pivot